# Reset button for Mtg Comander app won't work

Tags: javascript, html, button, counter, reset

here is my javascript:

```
let P1life = 40;
let P2life = 40;
let P3life = 40;
let P4life = 40;

//Player 1 Life
document.getElementById("P1LifeDown").onclick = function(){
    P1life-=1;
    document.getElementById("P1LifeTotal").innerHTML = P1life;
}

document.getElementById("P1LifeUp").onclick = function(){
    P1life+=1;
    document.getElementById("P1LifeTotal").innerHTML = P1life;
}

//Player 2 Life
document.getElementById("P2LifeDown").onclick = function(){
    P2life-=1;
    document.getElementById("P2LifeTotal").innerHTML = P2life;
}

document.getElementById("P2LifeUp").onclick = function(){
    P2life+=1;
    document.getElementById("P2LifeTotal").innerHTML = P2life;
}

//Player 3 Life
document.getElementById("P3LifeDown").onclick = function(){
    P3life-=1;
    document.getElementById("P3LifeTotal").innerHTML = P3life;
}

document.getElementById("P3LifeUp").onclick = function(){
    P3life+=1;
    document.getElementById("P3LifeTotal").innerHTML = P3life;
}

//Player 4 Life
document.getElementById("P4LifeDown").onclick = function(){
    P4life-=1;
    document.getElementById("P4LifeTotal").innerHTML = P4life;
}

document.getElementById("P4LifeUp").onclick = function(){
    P4life+=1;
    document.getElementById("P4LifeTotal").innerHTML = P4life;
}

//Reset Button
document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function(){
    life=40;
    document.getElementById("P1LifeTotal, P2LifeTotal, P3LifeTotal, P4LifeTotal").innerHTML = life;
```

my increase and decrease buttons work but my reset button doesn't. i'm trying to reset everything back to 40. i'm trying to select all of the individual life total elements in one press of a button.